# How to set Neo4j conf in docker?

Tags: docker, neo4j

I used to run Neo4j separately and then my application interacted with it as required. Every time I fresh installed Neo4j, I had to go to `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` and comment this one line:

```
dbms.directories.import=/var/lib/neo4j/import
```

by putting a `#` in start of it to make things work for me. By default this line wasn't commented.
 
Anyways, I am moving to `docker` now, and I want to know how to change that line in `docker` environment?

Here's my portion of `neo4j` in docker file.

```
neo4j:
    container_name: neo4j_container
    restart: always
    image: neo4j:3.5.3
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "6477:6477"
      - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7474
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6477
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7687
```

The image of `Neo4j` I am using, as you can see is `neo4j:3.5.3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing

```
volumes:
  - /:/var/lib/neo4j/import
```

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the official docker image, you can specify a local folder as the neo4j import folder by adding this line to your command : `--volume=/home/bsimard/my_project/neo4j/import:/import`

As you see here, I'm mouting my local folder `/home/bsimard/my_project/neo4j/import` to the `/import` folder of the image, and this `/import` folder is used by Neo4j inside docker.

You can take a look at the list of the volumes that the docker uses : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/docker/introduction/#docker-volumes

And you can also change any configuration of Neo4j just by providing some environment variables on your docker command. See here : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/docker/configuration/#docker-environment-variables

Cheers

Comment: thanks for your reply but the thing is, I don't want to specify any import folder. When I was commenting that line in conf file, I wasn't giving any alternate location of import. My query manages that. Point being I don't want neo4j to look at any certain folder for import, it should work like it worked by me commenting that line. I hope I am making sense

Comment: So by commenting this line, Ndo4j is using its default value. And the default value is the `NEO4J_HOME/import` folder. When you install Neo4j with a package manager, this configuration is set, to respect the standard location of a unix  server. So in your case with docker, you have nothing to do.

Comment: I feel like problem lies somewhere else. I am having an error when I run through docker that neo4j is not running pls make sure it is running. I have mapped the docker ports with my OS ports and I can open browser and see that neo4j is running fine. As u can see in code above, all ports are mapped too. Do u think I am using neo4j image wrong?